# Render sidebar for some pages in App.js ReactJs

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I want to render sidebar for all pages apart from login and signup. Just wanted to confirm is there any other optimum way to do it, and to manage 404 page in this scenario.

```
return loading ? (
    <p>loading</p>
  ) : (
    <>
      <Router>
        <div className="app">
          <NavBar />
          <ToastContainer />
          <Switch>
            <Route path={LOGIN_ROUTE} component={LoginPage} exact />
            <Route path={SIGNUP_ROUTE} component={SignupPage} exact />
            <div className="app-container">
              {showSidebar && <Sidebar />}
              <div className="app-main">
                <Switch>
                  <Route path={HOME_ROUTE} component={HomePage} exact />
                  <Route
                    path="*"
                    component={() => (
                      <NotFound setShowSidebar={setShowSidebar} />
                    )}
                  />
                </Switch>
              </div>
            </div>
          </Switch>
        </div>
      </Router>
    </>
  );
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can split your router configuration code into two components one has authentication routes and other one has home routes. So you can include your navbar into the home component. For example,

```js
// In router.js

<Router>
  <Route path="/auth" component={AuthComponent} exact />
  <Route path="/home" component={HomeComponent} exact />
  <Route path="*" component={() => (<NotFound setShowSidebar=       {setShowSidebar} />)}/>
</Router>

// In AuthComponent

<Router>
  <Route path="/signin" component={SigninComponent} exact />
  <Route path="/signup" component={SignupComponent} exact />
  <Route path="*" component={() => (<NotFound setShowSidebar=       {setShowSidebar} />)}/>
</Router>

// In HomeComponent

<div>
  <Navbar />
  <Router>
  <Route path="/signin" component={SigninComponent} exact />
  <Route path="/signup" component={SignupComponent} exact />
  <Route path="*" component={() => (<NotFound setShowSidebar=       {setShowSidebar} />)}/>
</Router>

</div>
```